# Facebook Login issue need business verification?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Does business verification affect facebook login? My mobile app can not use facebook login now[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2iFc.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pMpD.jpg)

I Try restore the public_profile permision to Standard access. but tips that facebook login need Advanced access

Comment: did you get any solutions yet

Comment: i had an app that was using a fb login auth then i got error whenever i tired to login then in my fb developer dashboard they wanted me to create facebook business account for my app but they are asking some documents for verification  that can't exist for an app so i just gave up on it and i left gg login and appl login only in my app any solution yet ?